# foreach loop Undefined index: title

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to output the results of some blog posts using a foreach loop but I keep getting the error **"Undefined index: title"**

```
<?php foreach ($post as $post_item):?>
<div class="postDiv">
<h4><?php echo $post_item['title'];?></h4>
<p><?php echo $post_item['summary'];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

here is my array when calling var_dump($post)

```
array(4) { 
["id"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(2) "15" 
    [1]=> string(2) "16" 
    [2]=> string(2) "17" 
    [3]=> string(2) "18" 
    [4]=> string(2) "19" } 
["title"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "234" 
    [1]=> string(2) "11" 
    [2]=> string(1) "2" 
    [3]=> string(3) "444" 
    [4]=> string(5) "title" } 
["summary"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "213" 
    [1]=> string(2) "11" 
    [2]=> string(1) "2" 
    [3]=> string(3) "444" 
    [4]=> string(7) "summary" } 
["content"]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "234" 
    [1]=> string(1) "1" 
    [2]=> string(1) "2" 
    [3]=> string(3) "444" 
    [4]=> string(7) "content" } }
```

I am a noob at php and I am also using codeigniter if that makes a difference here (I dont think it should). If I use the following code I can print out the posts for the title only but this is not what I want as I want to add in more fields later

```
<?php foreach ($post['title] as $post_item):?>
<div class="postDiv">
<h4><?php echo $post_item;?></h4>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

---

Here is my final code that worked for me

```
<?php 
foreach (array_reverse(array_keys($post["id"]), true) as $key):?>
<div class="postDiv">
<h4><?php echo $post['title'][$key];?></h4>
<p><?php echo $post['summary'][$key];?></p>
<p><?php echo $post['content'][$key];?></p>
<div style="float:right">
    <p><?php echo anchor('admin/edit/'.$post['id'][$key],' [edit]');?></p>
    <p><?php echo anchor('admin/delete/'.$post['id'][$key],' [delete]');?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: That is the $key of each array value in `$post`. In fact, you should be getting the same error with `$post_item['summary']`.

Comment: sorry yes i did get the same error for summary

Comment: Hi Carlos. I did fix it based on the comment below. I will post the full code later today

Comment: @malkocoglu I didnt want to blame your code,sorry for the misunderstanding.What I said will not work is not the code,that is ok,but the solution.For this current problem its a workin solution,but I think the real problem is one step before.Lets see:2nd level is not an asociative array,so `array_keys($post["id"])` is the same as a `for` from 0 to `count($post["id"])-1`.Also,items are mixed up.Probably thats not the best array and probably you can have some further errors derived from all this.In other blogs you would find an array where every item in the first level is a post, with its own data

Comment: @Carlos Robles, I agree with you... B/R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is somehow misaligned for your design.

```
<?php foreach (array_keys($post["id"]) as $key):?>
<div class="postDiv">
    <h4><?php echo $post['title'][$key];?></h4>
    <p><?php echo $post['summary'][$key];?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: sorry im afraid I did misread something or I made a mistake explaining what I saw that I dont think its fully correct. I deleted the comment here and will explain myself in the other one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your post information is split across multiple array keys based on a numeric reference, so you can use that numeric key reference to access the sibling array keys which contain the rest of your data.

```
foreach($post['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $title = $post['title'][$key];
    $summary = $post['summary'][$key];
    $content = $post['content'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for you understanding:
with  foreach ($a as $k) you are iterating an array $a, and putting in each iteration, one first level element in $k.

So, in the first iteration,

$post_item will be

```
 array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(2) "15" 
    [1]=> string(2) "16" 
    [2]=> string(2) "17" 
    [3]=> string(2) "18" 
    [4]=> string(2) "19" }
```

in the second, $post_item will be:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "234" 
    [1]=> string(2) "11" 
    [2]=> string(1) "2" 
    [3]=> string(3) "444" 
    [4]=> string(5) "title" }
```

and so on.

I dont even think that this secodn level indexes, 0,1,2,3,4,5 has an specific meannig to you, and for sure, if you do that    `foreach( array_keys($post["id"]) ...)`  would be the same as just iterating from harcoded 0 to count($post), and if you iterate  `foreach(  $post["id"] as $k)` and then use $k as index to the other elements, that wouldnt work alos, since the values of id, are not the keys of any other elements. so you will get many undefined index warnings.

and also im not sure if the values, the right side of every element, are actually any kind of usefull information for you. So, we could find some tricks here to get the result that you want, but what you need to fix is one step before, when you create $post